# How do I flag email for recipients with Outlook APIs in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, api, email, outlook, task

I want to send an email via the Outlook API in MATLAB and I also want to create a task in the recipients' Outlook.

I have tried taking a look at the Outlook API documentation, but all I could find was a reference to 'FlagStatus', which is not a parameter available for 'olMail'.

```matlab
% Connect to Outlook
outlook = actxserver( 'outlook.Application' );

% Create email
email = outlook.CreateItem( 'olMail' );

% Add email properties
email.To = address;
email.Subject = subject;
email.Importance = 'olImportanceHigh';
email.BodyFormat = 'olFormatHTML';
email.HTMLBody = body;

% Add task properties
email.TaskSubject = taskName;
email.TaskStartDate = datestr( today, 'dd/mm/yyyy' );
email.TaskDueDate = datestr( today + 12, 'dd/mm/yyyy' );

% Set reminder
email.ReminderSet = true;
email.ReminderTime = datestr( today + 7 + 9/24, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM' );

% Send email
email.Send;
```

The expected behavior would be the same as selecting the option as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is related to the [`FlagRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.flagrequest) property. To see what it does, run `email.Display()` after executing your code - you should notice an Outlook "new message" window open. This is what you would see initially,

[image]

Then, if you execute:

```
% Flag for recipient
email.FlagRequest = "<NAME OF FLAG HERE>";
```

You'd get:

[image]

... which is the same message that would appear when setting this flag manually through the Outlook GUI. Two caveats:

1. If you open the flag menu after running the command, it would show that a **local** flag would be created, instead of a **remote** one. This looks like an outlook bug.
2. The remote flag time/date is what you put in `ReminderTime`. I think it would be better to set `FlagRequest` before `ReminderSet` and `ReminderTime` for it to be reflected correctly in the GUI (when using `email.Display`).

Comment: Thanks! I tried it out and it does indeed seem to work.
I think I had used it already, but since it did not show with 'Display' I just assumed it was not the correct property. 
Would be nice to report this to Outlook.